# How do I disable touch pad on

Tags: touchpad

I usually disable my touch pad with Fn/F6 but this no longer works.  I suspect I have altered the system by inadvertently hitting a wrong key.  What do I do?

Comment: What laptop are you using? At any rate, have you tried disabling the touchpad on Device Manager?

Comment: Please mention what laptop you have (I assume it is a laptop?), what operating system you are running (some kind of Windows?), explain why you have tagged it with "touchscreen" and then only talk about "touchpad".

Answer (score 0):

If your pc is installed with the touch-pad driver, then you will(usually) have an icon in the system tray to manage touch-pad.
**Check for the touch-pad driver icon in the system tray**(My laptop is installed with synaptics touch-pad driver,so in my system tray I have an icon for synaptics pointing device).
 If it is there, click on it and you can see various controls to manage it.Look for the option to enable/disable it.
If it's not there then go to **control panel** search for **Device Manager** ,open device manager check for your touchpad device(will be under Mice and other Pointing Devices) Disable it.

And if you want to get back the **Fn/F6** functionality to disable the touch,try reinstalling the touchpad driver.